# ie7 and ie8 Unable to get value of the property

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, datatables

I am trying to build a table using jQuery Datatables. Everything works on all browsers except ie7 and ie8.

Here is the error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'sName': object is null or undefined
```

Here is the JS code:

```
var jsonData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
   var obj = docs[i];

   var row = [];

   row.push('<input type="checkbox" class="article_checkbox" />');

   for (var j = 1; j < columns.length; j++) {

       var value = obj[columns[j].sName];
       console.log(value);
       row.push(value);
   }

   jsonData.push(row);
};
```

My only thought is that the JSON response had a loose comma somewhere but I ran it through jsonlint and it came back valid.

Any ideas on this nasty lil' thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Use console.log on columns[j]

Comment: Hi @cwallenpoole,
Thanks for your response. Here is what is returned in the console. 
(A shortened version due to character limit in comments here)

Object { sName="hasAlikeDocuments", bVisible=false}
Object { sTitle="Date", sName="createDateDisplay"}
Object { sTitle="Source", sName="sourceName"}
Object { sTitle="Articles", sClass="dt_title", sName="title"}
Object { sTitle="Quick Tools", sClass="dt_tools"}
Object { sName="isArchived", bVisible=false}
Object { sName="isTranslatable", bVisible=false}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the sName definitions had to be wrapped in double quotes : )

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and the issue was that I had an additional `,` in the end of my array.

Comment: Many thanks! I had a similar problem and spent the whole morning trying to figure it out. I would never have suspected the comma at the end of the list.